# Rendering a List on Freemarker template from Spark web Framework

Tags: java, web, frameworks, freemarker, spark-java

I have the following method that renders a list of users on the template, but I got a 500 Internal Error when firing up Spark in IntelliJ.

```
private void renderTemplate() throws IOException, TemplateException {
        List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add("John Doe");
        users.add("Tony Doe");

        get("/admin", (request, response) -> {
           return new ModelAndView(users, "spark/template/freemarker/admin_template.ftl");
        }, new FreeMarkerEngine());
    }
```

**The content of my admin_template.ftl is:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Administration</title>
</head>
<body>


<h1>My Admin</h1>

<#list users as user>
    <h2>$user</h2>
</#list>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to render the list on freemarker template? thanks for replies!

Comment: tonygw : the answer by @nwk works fine and also to catch the error.
you can include one error.ftl and call that to display any error message.
Basically try to use try/catch block. so when you get an error either log it. and display that error page. and that way you can see the logs to find the error

Answer (score 2):

To render the list change

```
<#list users as user>
    <h2>$user</h2>
</#list>
```

to

```
<#list users as user>
    <h2>${user}</h2>
</#list>
```

in `admin_template.ftl` and alter `renderTemplate` to read as follows:

```
private void renderTemplate() throws IOException, TemplateException {
        List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add("John Doe");
        users.add("Tony Doe");

        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        attributes.put("users", users);    

        get("/admin", (request, response) -> {
           return new ModelAndView(attributes, "spark/template/freemarker/admin_template.ftl");
        }, new FreeMarkerEngine());
    }
```

If this does not resolve the problem there may be a separate issue with `FreeMarkerEngine` that is causing the error messages  "500 Internal Error", namely, that your `FreeMarkerEngine` object fails to find the template file `admin_template.ftl` at runtime. See the answer to [FileNotFoundException when loading freemarker template in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14761732/3142963) for details on how to deal with that.